# Slow index scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have table with index:

```
Table:
Participates (player_id integer, other...)

Indexes:
"index_participates_on_player_id" btree (player_id)
```

Table contains 400kk rows.
I execute the same query two times:

Query: `explain analyze select * from participates where player_id=149294217;`

First time:

```
 Index Scan using index_participates_on_player_id on participates  (cost=0.57..19452.86 rows=6304 width=58) (actual time=261.061..2025.559 rows=332 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (player_id = 149294217)
 Total runtime: 2025.644 ms
(3 rows)
```

Second time:

```
 Index Scan using index_participates_on_player_id on participates  (cost=0.57..19452.86 rows=6304 width=58) (actual time=0.030..0.479 rows=332 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (player_id = 149294217)
 Total runtime: 0.527 ms
(3 rows)
```

So, first query has big `actual time` - how to increase speed the first execute?

**UPDATE**
Sorry, How to accelerate first query?)

Why index scan search so slow?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in execution time is probably because the second time through, the table/index data from the first run of the query is in the `shared buffers` cache, and so the subsequent run of the query takes less time, since it doesn't have to go long-path to disk for that information.

**Edit:**

Regarding the slowness of the original query, does the table have a lot of `dead tuples`? Those can slow things down considerably. If so, `VACUUM ANALYZE` the table.

Another factor can be if there are long-ish `idle transactions` on the server (i.e. several minutes or more). Due to the nature of `MVCC` this can also slow even index-based queries down quite a bit.

Also, what the `query planner` is expecting for the results vs. actual is quite different, so you may want to do an `ANALYZE` on the query beforehand to update the stats.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Take a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html and check out for some tuning for using more memory. This can speed up your search but will not give you a warranty (depending on the answer before)!

2.) Transfer a part of your tables/indexes to a more powerful tablespace. For example a tablespace based on SSDs.